# Subobjects correspond to subgroups / subrings / submodules

Tags: category-theory

I read in MacLane that subobjects do correspond to subgroups and etc in standard categories. I don't understand why. So, a subobject of $a$ is a class of monic arrows $u : s \rightarrow a$ such that for any other arrow $v : s^\prime \rightarrow a$ from the class there's an isomorphism $\theta : s \rightarrow s^\prime$ such that $u = v \theta$. Now let's say we're in the category of abelian groups. There should be a 1-1 correspondence between subobjects of $a$ and subgroups of $a$. Let's say I have a monic $u : s \rightarrow a$. I relate to it the subgroup $\text{Im} \, u$, so I have an arrow $\imath : \text{Im} \, u \rightarrow a$. It's clear that I can find $v : S \rightarrow \text{Im} \, u$ such that $u = \imath v$. However, monics in the category of abelian groups may not be injective, so this $v$ may not be invertible (in the notation of MacLane, I can only show that $\imath \leq u$). How can I show that $\imath \equiv u$? I.e. how can I show that there is a map $v^\prime : \text{Im}\, u \rightarrow S$ such that $uv^\prime = \imath$?

Comment: For algebraic categories (in a technical sense, but one that covers most things studied in abstract algebra other than fields), it is always the case that the monomorphisms are injective homomorphisms. This is because the underlying set functor is a right adjoint and thus preserves monomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks. I recalled vaguely an exercise from category theory that says there's a monomorphism that's not injective (the usual cover of the circle by the real line), but I realized that it's a mnomorphism only for a subcategory of abelian groups..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Monics in the category of abelian groups are exactly the injective homomorphisms of groups.

"I read in MacLane that subobjects do correspond to subgroups and etc in standard categories. I don't understand why.":

If you define subobjects of $X \in \mathcal{C}$ as monomorphisms with codomain $X$, then this notion would not reflect the classical notion of subsets, subgroups etc. That is because you get too many different (categorical) subobjects that correspond to the same "substructure". 
Consider for example the singleton set $X = \lbrace x \rbrace$. The set $X$ has two subsets, namely the empty set $\emptyset$ and itself. We can easily find more monics though as for example $\emptyset \rightarrow \lbrace x \rbrace$, $\lbrace 1 \rbrace \rightarrow \lbrace x \rbrace$, $\lbrace 2 \rbrace \rightarrow \lbrace x \rbrace$ and $\lbrace 3 \rbrace \rightarrow \lbrace x \rbrace$, $...$ are monics (= injective maps in **Set**). Therefore we want to see all the latter ones (actually all the maps from singletons to $X$) as the same, namely as $\lbrace x \rbrace \rightarrow \lbrace x \rbrace$. That is the reason for taking the isomorphism classes of monics.

Try to understand the case of abelian groups once more and I will help you in case of problems.

Comment: +1. Put another way, a monic with codomain $X$ is a *name for a* subobject of $X$, and two monics $i,j:D_i,D_j\rightarrow X$ are names for the same subobject iff there is an iso $e: D_i\cong D_j$ such that $je=i$.

Comment: That is a nice way to put it, yes. Thanks for the addition.